# Asymptotics of a nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Consider the partial differential equation with boundary conditions
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \varepsilon \bigg( (u+1)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg), \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0 \quad \text{at} \quad  x=0,1 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
for $t\in[0, \infty)$, and where $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Let's suppose I want to find an asymptotic solution of (1). To leading order $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$, so that $u$ just takes on the form of the initial conditions, which can't be right. Alternatively, one could try scaling $t=\tau/\epsilon$ where $\tau =\mathcal{O}(1)$. This would remove $\varepsilon$ from (1) but wouldn't leave an equation that's easier to solve than the original.

My questions: (1) How would you approach finding an asymptotic solution to this problem? (2) if the correct approach is to introduce the coordinate $\tau =\mathcal{O}(1)$, then why? Surely this coordinate just implies that you need to scale time to be large, which isn't intuitive to me. (3) If anyone knows of a solution to equation (1) then please feel free to provide it. Thanks

Comment: transform away the $u+1$ to $u$

Comment: This is a transport equation with local transport speed $-\varepsilon(u+1)$. As $\varepsilon\to0$, the advection speed goes to zero, so $u$ taking the form of the initial conditions makes sense. Additionally, this is very close to the well-studied inviscid Burgers' equation, for which there are many estimates on solution behavior such as the development of shocks, etc.

Comment: I don't think the problem is well posed. There are no right travelling waves and hence there is no condition to apply at the right boundary (see answers [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5425/strange-oscillation-when-solving-the-advection-equation-by-finite-difference-wit?rq=1) and [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/conservation-of-a-physical-quantity-when-using-neumann-boundary-conditions-appli)). The conserved quantity $\epsilon(u^{2}/2+u)$ can be evaluated at the boundary. Having two boundary conditions for a first order PDE means it is overdetermined.

Comment: Further, by the method of characteristics, the general solution is given implicitly by $$u = f(x + \epsilon (u + 1) t)$$ Then, as $$u_{x} = (1 + \epsilon t u_{x}) f' \implies u_{x} = \frac{f'}{1 - \epsilon t f'}$$ The boundary condition at $x = 0$ implies $f'(\epsilon (u(0, t) + 1) t) = 0$ which is itself dependent on $u$ at the boundaries, similarly at $x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $u_\varepsilon$ by $u(x,t) = u_\varepsilon(x,\varepsilon t)$. Then $\partial_t u = \varepsilon \partial_t u_\varepsilon$ and $\partial_x u = \partial_x u_\varepsilon$. Therefore
$$\partial_t u_\varepsilon = (u_\varepsilon + 1)\partial_x u_\varepsilon.$$
The function $u_\varepsilon$ clearly independent of $\varepsilon$, so let's write $w = u_\varepsilon$. Then
$$\partial_t w = (w + 1)\partial_x w,$$
and
$$u(x,t) = w(x,\varepsilon t) \approx w(x,0) + w_t(x,0)\varepsilon t = u(x,0) + (u(x,0)+1)u_x(x,0) \varepsilon t.$$
This may be the kind of expansion you're looking for?